# PHPExcel - Existing array functions get converted into normal functions?

Tags: php, excel

Greetings all,

I'm trying to write a script that loads an existing spreadsheet containing a number of array formulas, add data to a worksheet and save it.  When opening the file after the script runs, the spreadsheet's formulas are no longer array formulas.

Below is the stripped down version of what I'm attempting:

```
$excelFile = new PHPExcel();
$fileName = 'blah.xlsx';

$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excelFile = $excelReader->load($fileName);

//first sheet contains formulas to process the resulting dump
$excelFile->setActiveSheetIndex(1);

// just to illustrate what's used when retrieving data
...
while($record =  db_fetch_object($queryResult)) {
  $excelFile->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $record->field);
}

$excelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelFile, 'Excel2007');
$excelWriter->save($fileName);
```

After the script runs, a formula that once appeared as:

> {=SUM(A1:C6)}

Now appears as:

> =SUM(A1:C6)

Thanks in advance for your insight and input

Tony

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the PHPExcel Cell object does not handle a formula element's attributes, so things like "t=array" would be lost by the time you get to createWriter.

To resolve this issue, we've made modifications to the cell and excel2007 reader and writer classes.

In cell.php:

```
private $_formulaAttributes;

// getter and setter functions
```

In reader/excel2007.php:

line 769 - after $this->castToFormula...

```
if(isset($c->f['t'])){
  $attributes = array();
  $attributes = $c->f;
  $docSheet->getCell($r)->setFormulaAttributes($attributes);
}
```

In writer/excel2007/worksheet.php:

line 1042 - after case 'f':

```
$attributes = $pCell->getFormulaAttributes();
if($attributes['t'] == 'array') {
  $objWriter->startElement('f');
  $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'array');
  $objWriter->writeAttribute('ref', $pCell->getCoordinate());
  $objWriter->writeAttribute('aca', '1');
  $objWriter->writeAttribute('ca', '1');
  $objWriter->text(substr($pCell->getValue(), 1));
  $objWriter->endElement();
} else {
  $objWriter->writeElement('f', substr($pCell->getValue(), 1));
}
```

hope this helps someone...

Comment: Had you considered advising the PHPExcel development team of these changes as a possible patch for the library?

Comment: I'm looking into the protocol on how to do so right now.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the patch. I'll see that it's included in the SVN code within the next few days

Comment: Thnaks Tony, I've now applied this patch to SVN. I'll look at extending it to other readers like Excel2003XML (I saw you'd made a minor change to identify cse formulae there) and Excel5 reader and writer, and providing the hooks in the calculation engine, and when getting and setting a cell value so that new cse formulae can be identified and created within PHPExcel.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the PHPExcel readers and writers don't yet support array formulas. I believed that the Excel2007 reader/writer did, but your experience suggests otherwise.